# set an htaccess iframe on your website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess, iframe

When I visited the apple site I noticed that there was an images.apple.com which is exactly the same as the homepage, so how do they to it. I don't think they just upload all the files of apple.com to images.apple.com like .html and .php I have seen some nice .htaccess earlier so I think they did it with the htaccess, so how can I do this. This doesn't work good, it will redirect me to my own page:

When you go to mij.sakesalverda.nl it will redirect you to sakesalverda.nl how can I solve this that it just become something like an iframe but still changing the url (which doesn't with an iframe) like apple.com and not this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=94.213.50.102
RewriteRule ^ http://www.sakesalverda.nl [L]
```

May they did it with javascript or jQuery...

Comment: This has nothing to do with iframes.

Answer (score 0):

They probably have `http://www.apple.com/` and `http://images.apple.com/` pointing to the same document root.

Note that you can get to identical content at both places:

- http://www.apple.com/ipodclassic/images/overview_hero.jpg
- http://images.apple.com/ipodclassic/images/overview_hero.jpg

and

- http://www.apple.com/ipodclassic/
- http://images.apple.com/ipodclassic/

There's probably no htaccess trickery here.

Comment: Oke, thanks but what do you mean with document root. I'm just 15 years old, so what does that mean?

Comment: @Sake https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=document+root&oq=document+root&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.677.2566.0.3302.14.10.0.3.3.0.220.1082.5j3j2.10.0....0...1c.1.43.hp..5.9.480.0.Ch1riM6XhWk

Comment: _“I'm just 15 years old”_ – “document root” is not a “dirty” word, so that info how old you are has no relevance here whatsoever …

Comment: And I'm dutch... so I have never heard of that before, but now I now what it means, thanks